# My website requires multiple refreshes to show new content

Tags: asp.net, web, browser-cache, page-refresh

I am in charge of updating a large e-commerce website, [tedbrownmusic.com.](http://www.tedbrownmusic.com) We hired an outside web developer to code the website, so I'm not very familiar with the back-end side of things.

**My problem:** The front page requires multiple manual refreshes in order for newly posted content to show up.

The front page is an ASP.NET storefront, separate from the rest of the site (which is run on Wordpress). The Wordpress site loads properly, but on the front page, I have to hit F5 a bunch of times for new stuff to show up (I am using the newest version of Chrome). In IE, it refuses to refresh at all. The cache has to expire before a user in IE can see new content.

The web developer said there was nothing he could do about it. But that doesn't seem like normal website behavior to me.

I have tried adding "no-cache" META tags to force the page to refresh every time it is visited, but it didn't work.

Any thoughts? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using css/js files, you can try to force browsers to load the latest CSS file by changing a version number. I think its called as css versioning.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="yourwebsitescsslocation/style.css?v=1324491378" type="text/css" />
```

if you change 1324491378 to some other value it will force browser to load css again rather than from cache. You can use changeset number or current timestamp as version number and make sure that it changes everytime you make changes to css.

see below article for some additional help:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/203288/Automatic-JS-CSS-versioning-to-update-browser-cach

Comment: I think we are onto something here. Thanks for your help.